# Transforming data by a constant

Tags: awk

I have a file like this

```
3 4 5 6 7 1
4 5 4 4 4 4 
2 2 3 3 2 1
```

and I want to multiple every data point by a constant (e.g. 10) to get the following output

```
30 40 50 60 70 10
40 50 40 40 40 40
20 20 30 30 20 10
```

I have been trying to do it like this without success

```
awk '{i=1; while (i<=NF) print $i*10; i++}'
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using a `while` loop, whereas a simple `for` would suffice:

```
$ awk '{for (i=1; i<=NF; i++) $i*=10}1' file
30 40 50 60 70 10
40 50 40 40 40 40
20 20 30 30 20 10
```

A `while` needs a finish condition and you are not providing none. Also, if the amount of loops to do is a fixed number, it is better to just use `for`.

Note that you were saying `print`, so that every field would be printed in a different line. By replacing each one of them and using `1` to print it afterwards, you keep the format.